# Update object property value when datagridview cell value is changed

Tags: c#

I've a combobox that allows me to choose between a series of classes.
When a class is choosen from the combobox a corresponding object is instantiated.

After that, a datagridview is populated, with two columns, one for the name of the properties of the object, and one for the value of that property.

Now, since the cell values of the datagridview for the values of the object are editable, when the dataGridView_CellValueChanged event is thrown i want to update the corresponding property of the object to the new value.

How can I refer to the object from the dataGridView_CellValueChanged? (datagridview is not bound to the object)

Comment: Where is the object when that event is triggered?  Is it a class-level member?  In some other scope?  Why not bind the `DataGridView` to the object directly?

Comment: The object is create in the class that popolates the DataGridview.  Ive not bound it to the Data Gridview because i want a row (not a column) for each property (and ive not found a way to do it)

Comment: If the object is a class-level member then you should be able to reference it elsewhere in the class, right?  (Unless this is ASP.NET, in which case you'd need to store the object somewhere such as session state or re-fetch it from persistence.)